# Is there any way to make Nodejs less of a disk-space burden?

Tags: json, node.js, mean-stack, node-modules, package.json

Specifically, why do I have to load/save thousands of node_modules files for each project that uses Node? It seems really redundant and inefficient to me, especially when the VAST majority of modules are the same from project-to-project. I get that this system was designed in case a developer needs to make different projects use different modules configurations. What I don't understand is; why was Node JS not designed to target a global node_modules folder and use the package.json dependencies list to specify which ones to use/not use? I assume that this would essentially work akin to how mongoose targets a MongoDB directory and only accesses the tables the specific project needs.

I'm somewhat new to MEAN so I doubt the developers didn't think of this, I'd just like to know the idea behind this decision.

Comment: Aren't you able to specify in the package.json where it looks for node_modules? [According to the doc, yes](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

Comment: Is this not solved by installing your modules globally?

Comment: npm install -g xxx

Comment: kinda, I was thinking in terms of a system where all modules are globally accessible but, unlike with a global install, not used by every project inherently.

Comment: I am under the impression that a global install tells every project that uses node to use the globally installed modules, is that not accurate?

Comment: A global install just puts the module in a global search path where it can be found from any project.  If you don't `require()` a globally installed module in, then it is not used.

Comment: You can also install modules in your own known directory location.  So you could install all your modules in `/node` and then `require('/node/express')` from all your projects.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to separately install modules for each project and you're OK with all your projects using the exact same version number of each dependent module, then you can install modules once in a shared location and use them from there.

You can either install modules globally (where NPM determines what the global shared location is) with something like:

```
npm -g install express
```

And, then use it like:

```
const express = require('express');
```

Or, you can install them into your own shared location:

```
cd /node
npm install express
```

Then, in all your projects, you would use:

```
const express = require('/node/express');
```

Comment: @DanielBraunstein - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

brew install pnpm

this is the only tool that was designed at helping with this problem